# how do I know the minimum date in a query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, postgresql-9.1

I have a column with various dates as timestamps!

"01/17/2014 08:25:13"

"01/17/2014 08:15:11"

"01/17/2014 09:55:12"

"01/17/2014 08:45:01"

...

...

how do I do a query to find the earliest date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

```
select min(stamp) from tbl
```

Or:

```
select stamp from tbl order by stamp asc limit 1
```

The first can also be used as a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html), if you need it on an entire set without grouping.

If you need the date in the stamp, cast it:

```
select min(stamp::date) from tbl
```

Or:

```
select stamp::date from tbl order by stamp asc limit 1
```